# Using GlobalFilters to cache invalidation is a good idea?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, cache-control

I am using ASP.NET MVC and EF.

To do cache invalidation I override the SaveChanges method and every time that SaveChanges is called, I update a field in database to flag that something changed.(I am using database to works with WebFarm scenario).

To clear the cache, I need to only query this field on database, if it is different from a static variable in C#, I clear the cache.

At first try, I called this method in BeginRequest, but BeginRequest is called for all request, including images.

Now I thinking if GlobalFilter is a good ideia, what do you think?

Thanks.

Comment: I found a problem. Route Constraints are executed before GlobalFilters

Comment: I think that is a better idea to clear the cache at DbContext constructor, since SaveChanges() mark the cache as invalid

Comment: Perhaps not make it so magic? There's some [interesting discussion on caching on the EF Design Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2008/07/09/transparent-caching-support-in-the-entity-framework.aspx).

Comment: I recently read your blog about dasBlog and how it scale. So I decided to use OutputCache on my blog engine as well. It´s Open Source and I published yesterday at Codeplex(http://fujiyblog.codeplex.com/). At the end, I used much more OutputCache than "Data" cache, because when I invalid OutputCache, I clear the Cache too. I am thinking to remove all Data cache and maintain just OutputCache´s

Comment: I am using at production and I didn´t have any problems